# Spotify API player update event

Tags: spotify

Basically I want to display the current track on a website.

I already searched quite a bit for a possibility to get notified when player state (play/pause, track, current position) changes.

My question:
Is it possible to get notified (socket, hook call) or is the only possibility I have to call the Web API like every second and fetch the state?

I fear that I'm running into rate limits when multiple users connect their accounts and display the current track.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's still no way to do that. To achieve what you'd like, you need to pool the Spotify API continuously.

You can however use the Spotify SDK that you can pass a function to be executed on playback state change. The SDK is incompatible with a few platforms ([see supported browsers](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/#supported-browsers)), but for those you could catch the SDK initialization error and then switch to continuous polling via the API. You will have a lot fewer requests then.

A second option would be to only update the currently playing song after the last song should have ended. When getting the playback state for the currently playing song, you could use the field `duration_ms` and `progress_ms` to calculate the remaining time of the song. Then schedule another API requests for when the song should have ended and you're good. Whether that's a good strategy for your use case or not depends on the type of playback and how often the playback changes in your app.

I hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it seems to be possible to receive player state events with a listener:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/guide/#playback-information-display

I haven't tested the Web version, I'm currently using the analogous Android APIs, and Android's seems to work for play/pause change and track change (but not for position change)